# How to select count of particular rows in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am writing a query like this...

```
select consumer_name,count(select * from consumer where product='TTT') 
from consumer;
```

I want filtered count... What will be perfect query for this?

Comment: you tagged with both mysql and oracle, please update the question and remove the tag which is irrelevant.

Comment: Can you give starting sample data and desired results?  Your current query makes no sense (because the results of the `COUNT()` have no relation to the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
select 
    consumer_name,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            consumer AS tbl
        WHERE
            tbl.product='TTT'
    )
from 
    consumer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select 
    consumer_name, COUNT(your_column_name which you want to count)
from  consumer
WHERE  tbl.product='TTT' group by colusumer_id;
```

Comment: You're missing a GROUP BY (unless I'm missing something).

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking to hide count ( and whatever in your output ) you can use alias :

```
select consumer_name,
count(select * from consumer where product='TTT') as A /*or any thing that you want */
from consumer;
```

or

```
select 
    consumer_name,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            consumer AS tbl
        WHERE
            tbl.product='TTT'
    ) as A 
from 
    consumer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` and insert the logic by `CASE` or `DECODE`

The `DECODE` one

```
SELECT consumer_name, SUM(DECODE(product, 'TTT', 1, 0))
FROM   consumer;
```

The `CASE` one

```
SELECT consumer_name, SUM(CASE WHEN product = 'TTT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
FROM   consumer;
```